# How to list all the single field indexes in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Recently, I started to create single field exemptions to reduce the Firestore storage for my project.

It works as expected, but I want to see all automatically created indexes. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly checked the Firestore console (both in Firebase and Google Cloud) and don't see a list of the automatically created single-field indexes there.

Even the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest) and the [`gcloud` CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/indexes/fields/list) seem to only show the exemptions, just like the console does.

So as far as I can tell, there is no way to get a list of all indexes.

Comment: I think users needs transparency over this info since it costs money :)